# Deployment projects not supported by msbuild: what are my options?

Tags: .net, msbuild, windows-installer, vdproj

I'm using TeamCity to automatically build my solution with msbuild and it seems that .vdproj are not supported. What are my options to build an msi/installer ?

1. Install Visual Studio on the build server
2. Use another installer (WiX, nullsoft, innosetup ?)
3. ?!

I already have TeamCity running and building a .zip and I'm looking for the fastest solution.

**Edit: I forgot to mention it's a WPF .exe application**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always try your hand at [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/), there is some support for using WiX through Visual Studio via the [Votive](http://wix.sourceforge.net/votive.html) WiX Project. Also there is the open source [WixEdit](http://wixedit.sourceforge.net/).

If you are using VS 2010 you can also take a look at the [InstallShield Limited Edition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h2db54x%28VS.100%29.aspx), which is included for free. If you aren't using 2010, then its a good reason to upgrade :)

Answer (score 1):

I've created something for a project I worked for some time ago.

Use [MSBuild Community Tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/) and take a look at the IIS tasks.

Comment: I forgot to mention it's a WPF .exe application